# Open OTF fonts with php - greek characters included

Tags: php, fonts, gd, imagettftext

So, as the title says, my task is to convert a given phrase to an image on server side (php GD) with a selected .otf font. The phrase can include not only latin characters but also greek and cyrillic.

PHP's imagettftext (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php) won't work with non-latin characters on .otf fonts (works ok with .ttf as it seems).

Any clues?

EDIT: Font *needs* to be .otf

Comment: Why not convert it to TTF then?

Comment: and do it for free at :http://www.freefontconverter.com/

Comment: my bad for haven't added this to the question: I _need_ the features .otf offers that aren't present in .ttf

Comment: What features are those exactly?

Comment: It is a good question whether you need those features for this image-conversion, or for something else. You could store them in two different formats.

Comment: for image conversio. To give you the full picture: It's for a store that sells fonts and it needs an online presentation of it's fonts in the way that I described it before. Enter text + choose font + other features like underlines or whatever + produce image.

Comment: well in short nothing in native php will do this, you will have to look at other applications you can run on the server.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Posting rough answer that seems to work for future people bumping on this post:

Solution seemed to be:
1) open OTF with LATEX server side
2) produce PDF
3) convert to image with ImageMagick library.

Answer (score 11):

Use [**`imagefttext`** function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefttext.php) instead. It has the same arguments and usage as `imagettftext`, but uses the **FreeType 2** library which supports OpenType and plenty of other font formats.

It doesn't support OpenType's layout tables however. See [FreeType 2's FAQ](http://www.freetype.org/freetype2/docs/ft2faq.html#other-opentype) for more info.

Comment: have you tried imagefttext with non-latin characters? Can't seem to get it to work either. Getting that annoying rectangle.